# "handy" instead of "mobile phone" (non-Germans)

Tags: word-usage, slang, is-it-a-word

Does anybody (non-German) ever use the word *handy* instead of *mobile-phone* in English?

Comment: Even *mobile phone* is anything but universal: in North America, it’s a *cell phone* or just a *cell*.

Comment: Isn't handy written with a capital letter, *Handy*? And my answer is, no. Always *mobile* and occasionally *cell phone* because Italian students will understand that better, and it's the most used term (I believe) in the USA.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So you both have never used the word "Handy" ? @Mari-LouA You are right. In german the all the nouns are written with a capital letter. I just adapted the spelling to the english language.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that English speakers would use a German word for their mobile phones?

Comment: You keep putting a space before your question mark. We are not French: we do not do that in English.

Comment: Also important to note before using it in the US, "handy" is a slang term for something totally unrelated to mobile phones. I leave searching urbandictionary as an excercise for those not at work.

Comment: @DigitalChris I was worried about that one.

Comment: @calculus The Germans may have imported an English word for their own purposes, but once they do that, it's a German word. Is your question really about the origin of the German word Handy? German etymology is off-topic here.

Comment: Speaking of adapting the spelling (too much): in English, all languages are written with a capital letter (just like in German).

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Thus, it seems that only we Germans use the word Handy for Mobile phone.

Comment: Someone told me the other day that in France they now say 'handy phone'; though when I was last there, a year or two ago, they were saying 'portable'. In South East Asia (Malaysia & Singapore) they talk about their 'hand phones'.

Comment: I have noticed recently that the use of 'mobile phone' seems to be declining.  They are just called a 'phone' nowadays.  The machine that used to be called a 'phone' is now a 'landline'.

Comment: calculus, the German use of the word *handy* is actually funny, from a British perspective.

Comment: @WS2 Thank you for your additional informations. So there are similar changes in languages at other countries.

Comment: @Tristan r I can imagine that.